# Allow absolutely positioned child to render outside parent with overflow: hidden

Tags: css, layout, overflow

How to allow for absolutely positioned element to disobey it's ancestor `overflow: hidden` and render outside it? The situation is complicated by the fact that there is a `position: relative` on the element between them in the ancestor hierarchy.

Here's a **[pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjXWPQ)**. In this situation how to allow red *inner* div to render at it's full height (300px), rather than being limited by *outermost* parent's 150px. I cannot remove `overflow: hidden` from the element - I'm using it to implement a collapsing panel. I also cannot move `position: relative` to one of *outermost* element's parents - it must stay at *outer* element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from the `.outermost` and create another element inside it with these rules: `overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;` and put everything else inside it and they won't get overflown.

```css
.outermost {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  position:relative;
}

.outer {
   position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hideOverflow{ /* Put all the content here that's overflowing content you want hidden. And leave content you don't want to hide outside this. */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hideOverflow">
      <p>Overflowing content inside this element will be hidden.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis imperdiet nisl, sit amet pretium eros rhoncus nec. Vestibulum viverra semper libero, nec commodo felis lobortis vel. Nam eu erat vel neque viverra iaculis. Mauris condimentum consectetur sem vitae semper. Duis bibendum mollis ex, vitae egestas velit. Nam vitae dolor ornare, vestibulum dui et, sollicitudin est. Duis tristique vehicula dolor et condimentum. Maecenas in tristique dolor. Mauris luctus tincidunt sem. Nulla sit amet tincidunt quam. Aenean quis semper enim. Morbi dolor tellus, porta eu feugiat non, pellentesque ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Mauris suscipit aliquet egestas.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how, but it works. Thank you. Can you explain to me what happens here?

Comment: You're putting everything that's overflowing content needs to be hidden inside that new element I pruposed. Everything left outside it won't get hidden. I can add code example if you need me to.